# Wordpress Frontend Page using Plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, permalinks, pages, next-post-link

I'm trying to create a front-end page using the WordPress custom plugin where I want to create a custom registration page. I have created a boilerplate plugin, where I can only activate and deactivate the plugin. How to create a new controller with a template in WordPress.

Comment: This is currently very broad of a question. Have you tried anything? There are a bunch of tutorials online for custom plugins. It might be beneficial to give one of the plugin development tutorials a try then come back if you have a specific problem or specific question. This [Sitepoint tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/an-introduction-to-wordpress-plugin-development/) seems to be a good introduction and links to a more detailed example at the end of their post.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I just at least want to know how to create a controller using a plugin.

Comment: It might be beneficial to read through the WordPress Handbook on [Introduction to Plugin Development](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/). I think what you're looking for is to create your initial plugin file with the proper header comments as suggested linked handbook. Expanded upon in [Header Requirements](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/header-requirements/)